# Как стилизовать кнопку с фоном выходящим за ее пределы и при наведении возвращающимся обратно?

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Возникла задача в проекте стилизовать кнопку в виде

[image: Фото 1].

Причем при наведении желтый блок должен встраиваться в рамки. Все файлы по [ссылке](https://yadi.sk/d/DpD4wvd63a8SNn).

Если с встраиванием вроде все понятно `transform: rotate()`, то с версткой проблемы, не получается разместить 3 элемента так, как на фото, буду признателен, если поможете с кодом. Использую в проекте bootstrap.

Вот наработки:

```css
#first {
    background-image: url(image/omk/1_UNI_Button_fance.svg);
    width: 290px;
    heigth: 312px;
}
 
#second {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(image/omk/1_UNI_Button_bg.svg);
}
 
button {
    background: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#">Бесплатная консультация</a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Семантически **не верно** ставить `<a></a>` во внутрь `<button></button>` или наоборот. Исправьте!

2 - Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью css transitions:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-color: #f7ec33;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #bdccd4 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #bdccd4 50%, #bdccd4 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  transform: scale(0.93, 1) skewY(-2deg);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

button:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1, 1) skewY(0deg);
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 7px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

span:before {
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

span:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Бесплатная консультация</span></button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!